# Binding dropdown list value for another dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create two dropdown lists the first one will select a year, the second one will then based on the selected value (which is the ID), will then only display form with yearID which equals the ID of the selected value. I think I have the right thing just it isn't working.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Year" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
    <asp:ListItem>-- choose one --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Form" DataValueField="ID">
    <asp:ListItem>-- choose one --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SignInOutConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Form], [ID] FROM [PForm] WHERE ([YearID] = @YearID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DbType="Int16" Name="YearID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SignInOutConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Year], [ID] FROM [PYear]"></asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

However when I load it, it says "The Type property of parameter 'YearID' cannot be set when the DbType property is set."

Comment: Did you try removing either `DBType` or `Type`?

Comment: Yes I did as I thought that was what was causing it, but then it gives the error "Input string was not in a correct format." for either one you remove.

Comment: The second error is good, that means you got past the first problem.  Now ensure that your data in the database is correct.  Is YearID in the database an integer?

Comment: Yep it is stored as an int value

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out my issue but will post the answer here for anyone else who has this trouble.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextFirstName" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Height="55px" Width="300px" Font-Size="40px" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter First Name" ControlToValidate="TextFirstName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextLastName" runat="server" placeholder="Last name" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Height="55px" Width="300px" Font-Size="40px" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Last Name" ControlToValidate="TextLastName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />

    <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/Next.png" ImageAlign="Right" />
</asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextReason" runat="server" placeholder="Reason" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Height="55px" Width="300px" Font-Size="40px" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Button2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Next.png" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Year" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Choose One --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Form" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Choose One --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SignInOutConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Form], [ID] FROM [PForm] WHERE ([YearID] = @YearID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="YearID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="int16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SignInOutConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Year], [ID] FROM [PYear]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I have changed is I have removed DbType="Int" from the control parameter. But then after changing a few other things I realised that my ListItem was causing the error that it wouldn't convert to an int as the value was an nvarchar, so I had to set the value of the ListItem to 0. This works fine, hope this helps anyone else who had my issue. :)